# Make sure NUnit Frameworks are in my git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, unit-testing, github, nunit

So I'm developing a program as a Visual Studio Solution written in c#. I have two projects, one of which is my actual project and the other which holds NUnit test classes. I am using NUnit 3.4.1. I need to make sure that the person evaluating this program can run my NUnit tests locally without needing to fetch their own copy of NUnit frameworks (per their instructions). What steps do I need to take to ensure that my unit tests will run as soon as the repository is cloned?

Comment: UPDATE: I currently have the nunit.framework.dll in my bin. Is that enough to ensure that the NUnit project will build and the tests will run in Visual Studio's test explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a best practice to ignore `bin/`, so I would suggest putting `nunit.framework.dll` in a `lib/` folder instead. Commit that file, update your `.csproj` to reference the assembly in `lib/` and you should be good to go.